# How to capture fingerprint with Windows Biometric Framework in Firebreath

Tags: fingerprint, firebreath

I've been trying to make FireBreath plugin that captures fingerprints with scanner. This code runs fine as just a console application (minus boost threading).

```
bool GopripFPrintAPI::winCaptureFPrint(const FB::JSObjectPtr& callback)
{
    boost::thread t(boost::bind(&GopripFPrintAPI::WBFCapture_thread, this, callback));

    return true;
}

int GopripFPrintAPI::WBFCapture_thread(const FB::JSObjectPtr& callback)
{

    unsigned long resultHandle = S_OK;
    WINBIO_SESSION_HANDLE sessionHandle = NULL;
    WINBIO_UNIT_ID unitId = 0;
    WINBIO_REJECT_DETAIL rejectDetail = 0;
    PWINBIO_BIR sample = NULL;
    SIZE_T sampleSize = 0;

    // Connect to the system pool. 
    resultHandle = WinBioOpenSession( 
        WINBIO_TYPE_FINGERPRINT,    // Service provider
        WINBIO_POOL_SYSTEM,         // Pool type
        WINBIO_FLAG_RAW,            // Access: Capture raw data
        NULL,                       // Array of biometric unit IDs
        0,                          // Count of biometric unit IDs
        WINBIO_DB_DEFAULT,          // Default database
        &sessionHandle              // [out] Session handle
    );

    // Capture a biometric sample.
    wprintf_s(L"\n Calling WinBioCaptureSample - Swipe sensor...\n");
    resultHandle = WinBioCaptureSample(
        sessionHandle,
        WINBIO_NO_PURPOSE_AVAILABLE,
        WINBIO_DATA_FLAG_RAW,
        &unitId,
        &sample,
        &sampleSize,
        &rejectDetail
    );
    ...
}
```

calling winCaptureFPrint() correctly starts WBFCapture_thread() and stops waiting at WinBioCaptureSample() but using fingerprint scanners does nothing method winBioCaptureSample() doesn't seem to get signal from scanner. I have been thinking that it's probably a focus issue so I have tried

```
resultHandle = WinBioAcquireFocus()
```

But it always fails. It gives General access denied error E_ACCESSDENIED.
Is there something in FireBreath focuswise that I don't know or am I doing something else wrong?

Comment: did you solve you isuue ? i'm having the same problem ^^ .

Comment: No. I had to abandon firebreath since I couldn't get it to work with WBF nor neurotechnologys Verifinger SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Install biometric devices Authentec so sensors will listen to your code

Comment: Well I don't use Authentecs fingerprint scanner and as I said in my first sentence WBF listens my code fine in test application outside Firebreath.

Answer (score 0):

Run Visual Studio as an Administrator and it should work.